# Can you hide in a bush to escape a 5-star wanted level in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

The Idea: To escape a 5-star wanted level by hiding in a bush.

Step 1: Get in a fast car and drive as fast as you can to get away from other police cars. Use the mini-map to avoid NOOSE cars (they are deadly)

Step 2: Once you escape the cops' view, and your stars are blinking, continue driving until you find the nearest thick bush, like you would a car.

Step 3: Go into sneak mode and hide directly in the center of that bush (so no body parts are protruding from the edges)

Step 4: ...

Profit? Will it work? Can you escape the cops this way?

Comment: Any reason not to try this yourself? I'm curious what the answer is.

Comment: The answer AFAIK is you can not do this. You can hide in a car under a bridge, but not on foot in a bush. But its been a while since I last played. So posting it as a comment.

Comment: No, the bushes do not collide with the NPC's line of sight. Hiding in a bush would only be effective against other human players.

Comment: Just tested it myself. Added a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it myself. It turns out you can in fact hide in certain bushes (some don't work, some do) to hide. There is a spot in LS near pillbox hill with some cover. Got to 5 stars, and used a trainer to activate invincibility (we're just testing to see if they can see me, not to see if they can kill me) and sure enough, when I hid simply by standing in the alleyway, a helicopter flew over and instantly my stars turned solid. When hiding in the bush, the stars stayed blinking.